How do I submit my Staging Ground question for re-evaluation?
I am a new user, and I have a question in the Staging Ground.  A reviewer voted to "Require Major changes".
I have replied to all comments raised by the reviewer, and I want to submit the question for re-evaluation so that someone will take a look and consider approving it.  How do I do that?

Note: while I am obviously not the user described in this question, I have been asked by someone in SG, and having never used SG as an asker, I have no idea how exactly this works.

If relevant: the user in question did not actually make any edits, but only replied to comments.  While in that particular case, that wasn't adequate (they needed to add the information to the question), one could imagine that an asker might reasonably feel that no edits are required (e.g., they believe the reviewer made a mistake, and have replied with reasoning why the question should be approved as-is).  If an edit is in fact required, an answer should include that.

Should this be [tag:faq-proposed]?

Re the "if relevant" I wonder if this is a potential point of confusion?  Does the asker think that it's enough for them to reply in the comments?  On an occasion where I asked for major changes, I did try to respond to their commented answers to clearly say "That's great, now put it in your question."

@Craig I try to explicitly give them an action to perform in my comments to prevent that, you might notice all of the comment templates have an edit link in them for the same purpose. You can add an edit link quite easily by just writing [edit]

@Craig I have a custom comment template for that: Please [edit] your question and include that in it. When it gets published, the comments will be cleaned up so all necessary information should be present in the question itself.

In order to submit your question for Re-evaluation and get it published, you must submit an edit to your proposed question that addresses the feedback that the reviewer mentioned in a comment.
It is important to note that addressing the feedback by replying to the comments will not change the question's status. If you want your question to be evaluated again, you must edit it. You may reply in the form of a comment if you want, but doing so will not change your question's status to "Re-evaluate", which is what signals to reviewers that your question needs a second look.
When the reviewer set your question as requiring "Major changes", they are required to have posted a comment about what kind of changes your question needs before it can be published. You might have received an e-mail or inbox notification about this event. When you return to your question, you should see a prominent box at the top of your question that features this feedback, along with a button to edit your question.
Here's an example of how that looks:

If your question was marked as off-topic or as a duplicate, a notice should be present at the top of your question which also features an "Edit question" button. Here's a link to how that would look. The process to get your question looked at again is the same as "Requires major changes".
You can also find a small "Edit" button at the bottom of your post, to the left of your username and avatar.
When you select one of the many buttons that let you edit your question and the window changes to allow you to modify it, the buttons at the bottom change to look like the following:

When you've made enough changes that you feel you've adequately addressed the feedback reviewers have given, you can choose the "Submit for re-evaluation" button. This will place your question into "Re-evaluate" status so that reviewers can decide whether it's suitable to be posted publicly.
Be careful: Selecting "Save changes" instead of "Submit for re-evaluation" will not prompt you to shift your question's status, and will not prompt reviewers to re-evaluate it. This means it's unlikely that a reviewer will take  another look at your question.

Sigh. That "save changes" button kind of feels like that need Stack Overflow has to make things as hard to understand as possible. There should be only one save button, and it is the one to submit for re-evaluation. But then again, maybe I'm weird for wanting things to be small and simple.

@Gimby This is something I asked for during the Beta and re-asked for on the announcement. It's extremely unclear to the average reader that "Save changes" doesn't allow re-evaluation and it's even more unclear and undiscoverable that the "What do Submit for re..."  button opens an explanation for each button. My recommendation was just a button that says "Save changes" and once you do, toss up an in-your-face dialog that says "RE-EVAL YES/NO?" (obviously more wordy than that but)

Is it worth noting that if the user gets multiple declined re-evaluations, they won't be able to resubmit for one again for a period of time (I also have no idea how that looks to the end user).
